# CreateProcessWithLogon in service returning code 5: access denied

Tags: delphi, winapi, windows-services

I have a windows service with StartType = stSystem.

It executes an application with the CreateProcessWithLogonW.

```
 usr := 'myuser';
 dmn := 'mydomain';
 pwd := 'thepassword';
 cmd := 'c:\myapp.exe -calculate';
 wdir := 'c:\';

 fillchar(si, sizeof(si), 0);
 si.cb := sizeof(si);

 if not CreateProcessWithLogon(
           PWideChar(usr),
           PWideCharOf(dmn),
           PWideChar(pwd),
           LOGON_WITH_PROFILE,
           nil,
           PWideChar(cmd),
           NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS or CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE or CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP,
           nil,
           PWideChar(wdir),
           si,
           pi
         )
        then
          RaiseLastOSError; // raises Code 5: Access Denied
```

Running this code outside the service, everything goes fine!

Why the CreateProcessWithLogon raises a system error Code 5: Access Denied ?

---

Can be this the cause?

[MSDN article on CreateProcessWithLogonW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682431.aspx) says:

> Windows XP with SP2 and Windows Server 2003:  You cannot call CreateProcessWithLogonW from a process that is running under the LocalSystem account, because the function uses the logon SID in the caller token, and the token for the LocalSystem account does not contain this SID. As an alternative, use the CreateProcessAsUser and LogonUser functions.

I'm using Windows 7 PRO x64

Comment: Can you specify which user account the service is running as? It could be LocalSystem, NetworkService, a named user, etc.

Comment: the service is running as LocalSystem

Comment: What happens if you don't use LOGON_WITH_PROFILE?

Comment: I added notes below about checking the Windows event log, so you might try that next.

Comment: iPath: I need to use LOGON_WITH_PROFILE because my program uses the registry HKCU.

Comment: you are running the service under the LocalSystem account, and as the documentation says: "You cannot call CreateProcessWithLogonW from a process that is running under the LocalSystem account".  So either change the user account that the service runs under, or switch to `CreateProcessAsUser()`, like the documentation says.

Comment: "Can this be the cause?" Er, yes!

Comment: @RemyLebeau, can you add that as an answer so we can upvote and accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running the service under the **LocalSystem** account, and as [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682431.aspx) clearly says:

> You cannot call CreateProcessWithLogonW from a process that is running under the **LocalSystem** account, because the function uses the logon SID in the caller token, and the token for the LocalSystem account does not contain this SID.

So either change the user account that the service runs under, or switch to `CreateProcessAsUser()`, like the documentation says.

Answer (score 0):

The LocalSystem account should have sufficient rights to read and execute any program on the local system (unless you have gone to specific trouble to deny it access to something). Given that, I'm guessing that maybe the program you're executing resides on some other computer. The reason this would cause a failure is because LocalSystem has no network identity and in general can't access remote shares. Can you check that the program definitely resides on a local drive, versus a network share (which could be masked by a mapped drive)?

If that isn't the problem, I would try using [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to debug the problem. This will display all file and registry activity on your system, including successful accesses and failures. If you run this and then reproduce the problem, I expect you will see an entry with a result of ACCESS DENIED, and that should point you toward the cause. You can use the filtering function to restrict the output to your service process and the process you are spawning. If you're running on Vista/2008 or later, you will need to run ProcMon with elevated rights.

You could also check the Windows event log, particularly the Security log. You may need to [enable audit logging](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310399) if it's not already enabled; I would enable "Audit object access", "Audit logon events", "Audit account logon events", and "Audit privilege use", including successes and failures. In my experience these changes can take a little while to become effective, so if you don't start seeing logs, you might reboot the test system. Once the logging is working, retry the CreateProcessWithLogon and see what events appear. You could also compare the series of events generated when things work with the series of events when things don't work, and that might help show what's wrong.

Comment: The file is accessible at local system. I already tried ProcMon but without problems reported during the call for CreateProcessWithLogon...

Comment: Tried auditing too, but without success.

Comment: Documentation for CreateProcessWithLogon makes it clear why this fails.